# How to check if a polynomial $p(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_0$ is a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V=\{p: \mathbf{R}\rightarrow \mathbf{R} \ |\  p(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_0 $ where $a_i\in \mathbf{R}$ and $a_n\ne 0\}$ (the set of polynomial functions of degree exactly $n$).

So to check this, I think we need to check the axioms, but I am not sure if $p$ represents a constant. Anyone helps?

Comment: $p$ is just a name, like $f$ in $f(x)$.

Comment: The condition $a_n \neq 0$ shouldn't be there, otherwise $V$ is not a vector space, since $0$ is not a polynomial of degree $n$ (and any vector space have a "$0$" element).

Answer (score 5):

The set of all polynomials of degree exactly $n$ can not be a vector space because you can subtract two polynomials of degree $n$ to get a polynomial of smaller degree. For example:
$$(x^3-x+1)-(x^3-2x-1)=x+2$$
$$(x^3-x^2+3)-(x^3-x+3)=-x^2+x$$
Thus, while the set of all polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$ would be a vector space, the polynomials of degree exactly $n$ is not.

Comment: But why does able to get degree less than $n$ mean that it is not a vector space?

Comment: If you can get a polynomial of degree less than $n$ by adding/subtracting two polynomials of degree $n$, then you can't exclude those polynomials of degree less than $n$ from your vector space. Otherwise, the vector space is not closed under addition, which is implied from the definition of a vector space.

Comment: So since closed under addition means if $x$ and $y$ are both from $V$, $x+y$ is in $V$, without polynomials with degree less than $n$ in $V$, the original polynomial cannot be closed under addition and therefore not a vector space? Sorry I am a bit confused here.

Comment: $V$ is the set of all polynomials with degree of exactly $n$. However, $x+y$ can be a polynomial that has a degree of less than $n$, as I showed above. Thus, for some $x, y \in V$, $x+y \notin V$ and therefore $V$ is not closed under addition. Because of this, $V$ is not a vector space.